# Is it normal to have visible lines below a second story room?

Tags: drywall, framing, ceiling

Are these lines normal? Looks like frame from second story?

[image]

Comment: What are we looking at here? Drywall? Precast concrete? Please revise to add enough detail for us to answer.

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers here.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a poor taping job. The installer probably did butt joints instead of the taper joints. The butt joints are two pieces of drywall where the joints are the same thickness as the rest of the drywall. They are much harder to level out and match the rest of the ceiling. The tapered joints use dywall that has narrower edges where the they are joined so the tape and mud are slightly recessed. The results are a seam that's more hidden and blends in with the rest of the ceiling.

Comment: They are "normal", but like JACK said, it's a poor taping job.   If you want a DIY fix, get some light drywall mud and a wide taping knife (at least 10" wide) .  Slam on some mud over the joint and taper it out.   I find best results if I apply  slightly uneven pressure by putting more pressure on the side of the knife that's away from the joint.   You should be able to get it done with one coat, but for someone learning, it may take two.  Go to You-Tube university.  There are tons of vids there to give you more complete advice than I did.

Answer (score 3):

Boring and normal drywall joints not done well.

You can go over them with joint compound and a wide knife and a wider knife and perhaps even a wider knife than that (letting each layer dry before moving to the next wider knife) to get a better blend, or you can put something like a brushed texture finish (or "popcorn" texture, if you'd like to hate yourself later when you tire of it) on the ceiling to disguise it, or both, or you can not worry about it at all as it's just cosmetic.

Comment: Or, of course, you can do something like a fake beam -- or go completely over the top to a mock-coffered ceiling treatment. (Which, since I like the look and have a 10' ceiling in the living room, I have been considering.)

Answer (score 2):

They look like joins in the plasterboard, the width you see is the tape that is used on the joints, so that the plaster can bridge the boards.

A modern plasterer could do a much better job. Often the problem is that the joists an batons are not level. In older houses, they would put a pattern on the ceiling to disguise it.

Comment: So this is normal? Is it something I should be worried about?

Comment: Expanded my answer.  Unless there is dampness or cracking, it should be fine.

Comment: The protocol is to tick the answer if you consider it correct and/or to upvote it.

Comment: And to give a checkmark to the answer you find most helpful. Though it's good practice to wait a while to see if an answer you like even better shows up, since AFAIK you can't reassign that once you've made the choice.

Comment: @keshlam you most certainly _can_ reassign a check mark! It does (according to conventional wisdom) tend to deter future answers that one might like better.

Comment: Good to know; never tried doing it. Thanks, @FreeMan. (Maybe we need a system that once a year reminds authors to recheck whether a better answer has appeared?)